# Add mysql unique constraints to apply to entries within a certain date

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

Am trying to add constraints to a mysql table, however i want this constraints to apply only to entries after a certain date. i.e the constraints is for all entries after `'2020-01-01 00:00:00'` and not before.

This the query am using, how do i add the time check if its possible. Thank you

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE unique_index(col1, col2, col3) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE tablename ( 
    entityvalue DATATYPE,
    entitydate DATETIME,
    additional_column DATATYPE AS (CASE WHEN entitydate >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
                                        THEN {constraintexpression}
                                        ELSE NULL END),
    UNIQUE (additional_column) );
```

Generated column is assigned to the expression to be constrained (unique, for example) if entity checkdate is reached, and NULL if not. Then it is used in UNIQUE constraint - NULL provides the uniqueness for any value before and for only constraint expression after.

If the version allows then additional column may be VIRTUAL.

---

Or use simplified version:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename ( 
    entityvalue DATATYPE,
    entitydate DATETIME,
    additional_column DATATYPE AS (CASE WHEN entitydate >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
                                        THEN entityvalue
                                        ELSE NULL END),
    UNIQUE ( additional_column ) );
```

NULL for rows before the date inhibits uniqueness check.

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6fec7b7c5e68fdf1e90737dbc9ff2de3)